# Extending a Protocol to extend Delegate Methods for NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

i am trying to overwrite the NSURLConnection Delegate but i dont know where to start, can someone please give some more kind of informations and a little bit sample code?

I want to extend the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate. And keep looking if the JSON-String i am becoming back got some error reporting for the user.

it seems to me the best way to extend the delegate. It is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending a protocol will let you add methods to it. However, if you add more methods to `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>`, that won't mean that `NSURLConnection`s will use them :)

Why can't you put your error checking code in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method i.e.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Check your json here
}
```

Comment: I want to implement a standard error checking in my connectionDidFinishLoading method. I don't want to check it in all of my Controllers. I would doubling code for this and i thought it would be the best to extend the connectionDidFinishLoading protocol.

Comment: Then I would write a generic object that created the NSURLConnection, made itself the delegate, did all of the data collection and error checking. All your controllers would use this object instead of an NSURLConnection. Your controllers would be a delegate of your new object, not a delegate of NSURLConnection. (You would have to write your own protocol but that's not too tricky).

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to achieve is the following:

- Create a `NSURLConnection` and configure it to fetch a JSON file.
- When the connection completes, check to see if the received file is satisfactory.
- If the file is not satisfactory then alert the user.

If my understanding is correct then you do not need to extend the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol. All you do need to do is implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate. The delegate pattern allows the behaviour of a class to be changed. (In other languages/frameworks the behaviour you explained would be implemented by subclassing. The URL Connection class would be subclassed and the methods and overridden to change the behaviour.) It may be worth your while reading [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

It's common for the class that created an object to be its delegate. The following code shows a the creation of a connection and accompanying delegate method implementations.

```
@interface SOViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> //this simply tells the compiler that SOViewController implements the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol. If you excluded you will get a compiler warning but the code will behave correctly. You should include it.
//...
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;
@end

@implementation SOViewController

//...

-(void)setupJSONFetch:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url]; //create a request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //create a connection and set self as the delegate
    self.connection = connection;  //keep a reference to the connection
    self.data = [NSMutableData data]; //create an object to store the downloaded data
    [connection start]; //go!
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //store the downloaded data
    [self.data appendData: data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
     //Check self.data is as expected
}

//...

@end
```

It's also worth noting that the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods got reorganised in iOS 5.

Comment: The only way for me is to write an own Class with my own delegates. I think thats the best way i can choose

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file :-

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<YourDelegate>{

}
@end
```

In your .m file :-

Implement the methods :-

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [connection release];
    self.responseData = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];


}
```

I think [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) may help you... :)

Comment: thats not that i exactly wanted. i know how to create a URL Conenction and fetching data of it. i want to do it generally.